# найти угол между вектором и осями координат

Tags: python, математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Полностью задача звучит так - построить плоскость по трем точкам и найти ее угол с осями координат. 
Для решения я строю нормаль к плоскости, нормирую ее и беру арксинус как написали в [посте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893410/how-to-get-the-tilt-angle-of-a-plane-defined-by-three-coordinates-in-python)
Но то, что получается мало похоже на правду. Что я делаю не так?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import plotly.graph_objs as go

points = [[6.5612, 5.3440, 2.4175],
           [1.2279, 6.1946, 4.5744],
           [9.1216, 9.3959, 2.6394]]

p0, p1, p2 = points
x0, y0, z0 = p0
x1, y1, z1 = p1
x2, y2, z2 = p2

ux, uy, uz = u = [x1-x0, y1-y0, z1-z0]
vx, vy, vz = v = [x2-x0, y2-y0, z2-z0]

u_cross_v = [uy*vz-uz*vy, uz*vx-ux*vz, ux*vy-uy*vx]
n = np.cross(u, v)
point  = np.array(p0)
normal = np.array(u_cross_v)
nn = (points[1] + normal)
d = -point.dot(normal)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(10), range(10))

zz = (-normal[0] * xx - normal[1] * yy - d) * 1. / normal[2]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=zz, opacity=0.5))  
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[x0, x1, x2],
                           y=[y0, y1, y2],
                           z=[z0, z1, z2],
                           mode="lines",
                          opacity=1.0))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[nn[0], x1],
                           y=[nn[1], y1],
                           z=[nn[2], z1],
                           mode="lines",
                          opacity=1.0))    

fig.show()


nn = n / np.linalg.norm(n)
angles = np.abs(np.arcsin(nn))
print("angles", angles)
v=[]
for i in angles:
  a=i * 180 / math.pi
  v.append(a)
print("angles", v)
```

Результат angles [19.08435917574169, 14.857700717809104, 65.44817677698197]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Углы нормали (любого единичного вектора) с осями - арккосинусы компонентов вектора, а углы плоскости - дополнение до pi/2, т.е. арксинусы этих компонентов, так что идея правильная. 
Проверьте на плоскостях с известными углами:

```
(0,0,0)(1,0,0)(0,1,0)  должно быть 0,0,90
(1,0,0)(0,1,0)(1,0,1)  должно быть 45,45,0
```

Upd: проверил, так и есть,